# get field from tree with fzf

Tags: bash, shell, fzf

I've tried something like this

```bash
tree -C | fzf --ansi | awk -F'|' '{print $NF}'
```

```
├── repo.git/
│   ├── folder/
│   │   ├── subfolder/
│   │   │   ├── output.0
│   │   │   └── traces.1
│   │   ├── subfolder/
│   │   │   └── fold/
│   │   │       └── subtree/
│   │   │           ├── .gitignore
│   │   │           ├── stamp-h1 item
│   │   │           └── stamp-h2
```

I want to grab `stamp-h1 item`, in other words the filename

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really have to use `tree` then you should use `tree -CQ` where `Q` quotes the filenames with double quotes.
So the *tree* output would become:

```
└── "repo.git"
    └── "folder"
        ├── "subfolder"
        │   ├── "output.0"
        │   └── "traces.1"
        └── "subfolder2"
            └── "fold"
                └── "subtree"
                    ├── "stamp-h1 item"
                    └── "stamp-h2"
```

And for getting the filenames you can apply a regular expression using `sed` for getting only the values between `" "`. So your code should be like this:

```bash
tree -CQ | fzf --ansi | sed 's/.*\"\(.*\)\"/\1/g'
```

With the code above if you select `repo.git` you will obtain:

```
repo.git
```

If you select "stamp-h1 item" you will obtain:

```
stamp-h1 item
```

Or if you want to print the value between `"` you should use:

```bash
tree -CQ | fzf --ansi | sed 's/.*\"\(.*\)\"/"\1"/g'
#Example output:
"stamp-h1 item"
```